# gcc -Wtype-limits with upper limits

Tags: c, gcc, types, compiler-warnings, gcc-warning

Given this snippet

```
#include <inttypes.h>

uint8_t test(uint32_t foo) 
{
    if (foo > 0xFFFFFFFF)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    if (foo < 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

compiling with `-Wall -Wextra` using gcc 12.2 gives **only** the following warning:

```
 warning: comparison of unsigned expression in '< 0' is always false [-Wtype-limits]
    9 |     if (foo < 0)
      |             ^
```

I don't understand why the first line `if (foo > 0xFFFFFFFF)` does not trigger the same warning.

Trying `if (foo > UINT32_MAX)` does not trigger any compiler warning.

is it a bug or a feature?

Comment: What does it compile to? Is the check optimised away?

Comment: using ```-O0``` or ```-O3``` will not change anything, optimisation occurs after this check

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/zvsofG5jE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These warnings are not mandated by the language rules, it's up to the compiler vendors to add them, or not. The fact the **gcc** warns you about the second `if` can be considered a courtesy. For this reason I believe we can't consider this a bug, unless you can spot this particular feature on the **gcc** documentation, that could change my view.

I checked **clang** for these warnings and sure enough it doesn't warn you at all, at least not with those flags:

https://godbolt.org/z/c7hbM3K5d

It's only when you try `-Weverything` it warns you of both cases:

```
<source>:5:13: warning: result of comparison 'uint32_t' (aka 'unsigned int') > 4294967295 is always false [-Wtautological-type-limit-compare]
    if (foo > 0xFFFFFFFF)
        ~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:9:13: warning: result of comparison of unsigned expression < 0 is always false [-Wtautological-unsigned-zero-compare]
    if (foo < 0)
        ~~~ ^ ~
```

https://godbolt.org/z/9b9q13rTe

+1 for **clang** in my book.

If you want to see these warnings in your build be sure to use the specific flag (`-Wtautological-unsigned-zero-compare` and `-Wtautological-type-limit-compare`), using `-Weverything` would be too verbose and flag many situations you don't need as mentioned in the comments.

---

Back to **gcc**, if you use a wider type for the comparison like for example `if (foo > 0xFFFFFFFF0)` then you get your warning:

```
<source>:5:13: warning: comparison is always false due to limited range of data type [-Wtype-limits]
    5 |     if (foo > 0xFFFFFFFF0)
      |             ^
```

https://godbolt.org/z/Edvz7aq3b

We can assume they forgot to include the max value for `uint32_t`, it can be an off by one mistake, or it can be that the warning implementation [focuses on types rather than values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75008026/gcc-wtype-limits-with-upper-limits/75008672#comment132367795_75008672), one can only speculate. You can [file a report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/) if you're adamant on having this particular warning working for `UINT32_MAX`, or at least get to the end of it, and find out what is the reason for this behavior.

Comment: I suspect from the behavior that the GCC warning is literal - it's about *types*, and comparing an unsigned 32-bit integer value to an unsigned 32-bit integer value doesn't trigger the warning because of that implementation.  Adding a value check may be difficult and/or deemed not relevant.

Comment: Note that the clang warning includes the name of the option to enable that warning, namely `-Wtautological-type-limit-compare`.  Then you can add that option to your Makefile instead of using `-Weverything`, which isn't meant for everyday use as it will tend to warn about many things that are perfectly fine.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with filing an enhancement request on gcc's bugzilla, that's the natural next step for the OP.